# Normalize comma separated foreign key

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have "element" and "authors" tables, where element table can have one or many authors, but tables are not normalized(some folk designed this long ago). eg:

```
element_id   ...     ...  authors
369561                    319,30,2496,544
```

DB is large enough, so i need some *SQL script* which will create and populate join table, for example:
"element_authors"

```
element_id | author_id
369561       319
369561       30
369561       2496
369561       544
```

I don't have idea how to write this script, any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general idea is to split the comma separated field into a set using `regexp_split_to_table`, cast each value to `integer`, and pair the results up with the `element_id` from the tuple we got the original comma separated field from.

For PostgreSQL 9.3, you'd write:

```
INSERT INTO element_authors(element_id, author_id)
SELECT
  element_id,
  CAST (author_id AS integer) AS author_id
FROM
  element,
  LATERAL regexp_split_to_table(nullif(authors, ''), ',') author_id;
```

or on older PostgreSQL versions I *think* in this case it's safe to write:

```
INSERT INTO element_authors(element_id, author_id)
SELECT
  element_id,
  CAST( regexp_split_to_table(nullif(authors, ''), ',') AS integer) AS author_id
FROM
  element;
```

Comment: Im using postgreSql 9.2 by the way.
For the first case i have following error:
http://pokit.org/get/?374cf4b6d78585f1d8a3924636bc0943.jpg

Comment: `LATERAL` was added in 9.3, so you'd have to use the second form.

Comment: Just one question more.
ERROR:  column "element_id" does not exist for the second case.
For line "SELECT element_id..."

Comment: I just overlooked table name is "element" not "elements"

Comment: @Srle Glad to hear it.

Comment: But again i have same error, \d element and \d element_authors output:
http://pokit.org/get/?1104d62f5f408b561f7787036359a116.jpg

Comment: Doesn't make much sense. Weird. Exact error message?

Comment: ERROR:  column "element_id" does not exist
LINE 1: ...NTO element_authors(element_id, author_id) SELECT element_id...

Comment: It is because ";" after SELECT LINE in the 2nd example i guess

Comment: thanks a lot i will definitely accept answer.
Just one more question, what to do in case that for some row in element table "autors" column is blank. How to omit rows from the 2nd query where "authors" column is blank

Comment: @Srle Try it on dummy data and see. You'll find that if the input to `regexp_split_to_table` is `''` it returns a single row with an empty field. If it's NULL, then zero rows are returned. So if you can have a blank `authors` list, you'll want to make sure that it's converted to `NULL` for input into `regexp_split_to_table` using a `CASE` expression or `nullif`. See edit. If you're not strict about the field, you may need to strip whitespace or do a regular expression match instead.